# Деепричастный оборот после слова "можно", ставить ли запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

*Рассчитать оптимальный объём порции и состав меню можно ориентируясь на среднестатистическое содержание витамина P в пищевых продуктах.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, так как деепричастный оборот
носит обстоятельственный оттенок и отвечает
на вопрос обстоятельства образа действия "КАК?",
а не на вопрос деепричастия.

Не нужно выделять запятыми деепричастия 
и деепричастные обороты в следующем случае:

если деепричастия непосредственно примыкают к глаголу 
и имеют значение образа действия:

Пишите (как?) не колеблясь.
Это упражнение делают (как?) сидя на стуле,
Старик шёл (как?) прихрамывая на правую ногу.